# Cuando pinto en un canvas, no me esta moviendo el rectángulo del contexto JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Por ahora no me da error, sólo me pinta el rectángulo pero no me completa mas nada, tenia otro código en el que si me pintaba, solo que no me rellenaba, voy a ponerlo también.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var onMove = false;
 var z = (canvas.width - 15)/2;
 var v = (canvas.height - 15)/2;

class Rectangulo {
constructor(){
 this.x = z;
 this.y = v;
 this.h = 20;
 this.w = 20;
 this.right = this.x + this.w;
 this.left = this.y + this.h;
}

 dibujar(){      
     ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.fillStyle = "black";
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y , this.w, this.h);
 }
 }

 var rect = new Rectangulo();

 rect.dibujar();

 function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
 var client = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { // devuelve un objeto
      x: Math.round(evt.clientX - client.left),
      y: Math.round(evt.clientY - client.top)
   };
  }

 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {   
  var mousePos = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(mousePos.x, mousePos.y)) {
     onMove = true;
     z = z - mousePos.x;
     v = v - mousePos.y;
     rect.dibujar(); 
  }
 }, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
 var mousePos = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
 if (onMove) {
     z = mousePos.x + rect.x; 
     v = mousePos.y + rect.y;
     rect.dibujar();
  }
}, false);

 canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
 onMove = false;
 }, false);
```

Comment: el codigo sirve, no da errores, solo no me cumple la funcion que quiero, alguna sugerencia de como puedo mover un objeto?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer con `ctx.isPointInPath(mousePos.x, mousePos.y)` ? ¿Comprobar que se ha "clickado" sobre el rectángulo?

Answer (score 3):

El principal problema del código es que en ningún momento modificas las propiedades `x` e `y` del rectángulo, por lo que siempre se dibujan en la misma posición.

En el ejemplo que te pongo a continuación he simplificado también el cálculo de coordenadas. Tomando la posición del cursor como centro del rectángulo a dibujar.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
// Establecer dimensiones del canvas
canvas.width=200;
canvas.height=200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var onMove = false;
// Posición del centro del canvas (posición inicial)
var z = canvas.width /2;
var v = canvas.height /2;


class Rectangulo {
  constructor(){
   this.x = z;
   this.y = v;
   this.h = 20;
   this.w = 20;
   this.IsPointInside = function(pos){
      let x = parseInt(this.x - this.w / 2);
      let y = parseInt(this.y - this.h / 2);
      return (pos.x >= x && pos.x < x + this.w
        && pos.y >= y && pos.y < y + this.h);
   };
  }

   dibujar(){      
       ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       // El rectángulo se dibuja para que el centro quede en x,y
       let x = parseInt(this.x - this.w / 2);
       let y = parseInt(this.y - this.h / 2);
       ctx.fillRect(x, y, this.w, this.h);
   }
}

var rect = new Rectangulo();

rect.dibujar();

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
 var client = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return {
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - client.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - client.top)
 };
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {  
  var mousePos = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  if (rect.IsPointInside(mousePos)) {
     onMove = true;
     // Modificamos la posición del rectángulo y dibujamos
     rect.x = mousePos.x;
     rect.y = mousePos.y;
     rect.dibujar(); 
   }
 }, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
 var mousePos = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
 if (onMove) {
   // Modificamos la posición del rectángulo y dibujamos
   rect.x = mousePos.x;
   rect.y = mousePos.y;
   rect.dibujar();
  }
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
    onMove = false;
  }, false);
```

```css
#canvas{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Intuyo que el OP quiere mover el rectángulo sólo cuando se hace click sobre él, por eso pregunté por la condición. Lo comento porque si lo aclara estaría bien añadir a la respuesta cómo detectar correctamente ese evento

Comment: Vale, ok. Tampoco acababa de entender el porqué de la llamada al `isPointInPath`. Ahora que lo comentas supongo que sí que la intención sería esa. A ver si lo aclara.

Comment: Sii. es para detectar que el mouse esta dando click en ese rectangulo

Comment: Ok. He añadido un método `IsPointInside` al objeto `Rectangulo` para comprobar si se ha pulsado sobre el rectángulo o no.